# Text in canvas to show in timed sequences using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6e6nwkpv/

I want to make the hidden canvas show, and the footer hidden when I click the button 'No.' But somehow they end up both disappearing.

Bonus: how does one make java words on html canvas appear(and disappear) in a time sequence?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<body>
    <div id="canvas" style="display: block;">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" height="300" width="500"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div id="buttons">
        <button class="clickBoo" style="margin-top: 40px;">No</button>
    </div>
    <footer class="change">
        Revised June 7th
    </footer>
</body>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(function() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        if (canvas.getContext) {
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.font="30px Helvetica";
            ctx.fillStyle = "white";
            ctx.fillText ('Boo!',400,50);
            ctx.fillText ('Boo!',10,200);
            ctx.fillText ('Tea?',300,200);
            ctx.fillText ('No?',200,400);
            ctx.fillText ('Sorry if I scared you.',20,40);
        }
    });

    $(".clickBoo").click(function() {
        $(".change").toggle("changed");
        $("#myCanvas").toggle("show");
    });

});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the footer but I think you need to use toggleClass('changed')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with this code.

1. As @Jackson suggest, you have used wrong jquery function [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) instead of [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).
2. Secondly, your footer has margin-top property set to -700px which cause this element to disappear since your canvas and "No" button in summary have about 400px height. So your footer is rendered about 300px above the screen.
3. By default your canvas **is** shown but it is rendered with empty content. So applying `show` class to your canvas does nothing.

Comment: thanks! so, I changed according to what you and @Jackson said, and without css hidden, it shows up as a red box, but how do I make it so that it becomes visible after I click the button rather than vice versa?

Comment: Just add property visibility:hidden to your canvas {
 z-index: 0;
 position: relative;
}